# How to "splice" an object?

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

**Here is what I want to achieve:**

A function called **Splice** which can take 3 arguments:

1. The first is an object.
2. The second is numeric.
3. The third is numeric.

It takes properties from an object and uses them for a newly created object.

Which properties are defined by the two numbers. The second argument indicates the position of the key/value pair that I want to start taking properties from and the third indicates how many I want to remove.

So for instance splice(0,2) refers to the positions 0 and 1 of the object having the following object: var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 2} and calling the function splice with the arguments obj, 0, 2 should return {a: 1, b: 2}

If the third argument is not passed it should default to 1.

This is what I have so far (not yet respecting the last part when only one number is passed in):

```
function splice(object, number, number2) {
    var newOjb = {};
    var count = 0;
    object.forEach(function(element, index) {
        count++;
            if(count <= number2 && count > number) {
                newObj[key]=item
            } else if (number == count) {
                newObj[key]=item
            }
    })
    return newObj;
}
```

However, I seem to use some wrong syntax as my console tells me my forEach loop is not a function and the code, in general, doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas for basic solutions (no fancy techniques)?

Comment: "*The second argument indicates the position of the key/value pair I want to start taking properties from*" but you don't have a guaranteed order of the keys.

Comment: Order is not important at that point.

Comment: But you want to be able to take stuff from, say, the "second" property and that will not be guaranteed to be the same thing every time.

Comment: If order is not important, `{a:1,b:2}` is as good a result as `{b:2,c:2}`, right? In that case your direct problem is that you're trying to call an array method (`forEach`) on an object; use `Object.keys(object)` to get the array of the object's keys.

Comment: @Nickolay you are saying forEach can't be applied to objects? Yet I don't get the suggestion that you propose.

Comment: Yep, forEach is [not available on generic Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype). See @barbsan's answer for a working example.

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(oldObject).slice(0, count))`

Comment: Check out mu updated code . It is as per your need in loop . @user2132380

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.entries(object).forEach(function([key, item], index) {` (Note: This will not guarantee order). You have also typo in `var newOjb = {};`

P.S. You don't need that `count`, you can use `index` in your conditions

`number` - index, `number2` - count

```js
function splice(object, number, number2) {
  var newObj = {};

  if (!number2) {
    number2 = 1;
  }
  Object.entries(object).forEach(function([key, item], index) {

    if (index >= number && index - number < number2) {
      newObj[key] = item
    }
  })
  return newObj;
}

let obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 2
};

console.log(splice(obj, 0, 2))
console.log(splice(obj, 2))
console.log(splice(obj, 1, 2))
```

Comment: not quite: 
splice({a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}, 2, 2) should be {b:2, c:2} which it isn't with that function 

splice({a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}, 0,2) should be {c:2} which it isn't

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: `Object.entries(object).forEach(function([key, item], index)` Does it mean in order to use forEach on an object I need this syntax? Where does "entries" come from.

Comment: You wrote in question that `splice({a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}, 0, 2)  // ...should return {a: 1, b: 2}`. Can you explain why `splice({a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}, 2, 2) should be {b:2, c:2}` and `splice({a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}, 0,2) should be {c:2}`?

Comment: You can read on [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) - it returns array of entries of object, each entry is an array, where first element is key and second is value. `.forEach` is implemented on Array so you need array to use `.forEach`

Comment: Right now this code operates on numbers of element instead of indexes, so for `(obj, 2,2)` it returns 2nd element: `{b: 2}`  and `(obj, 0,2)` returns the same result as `(obj, 1,2)`

Comment: sorry my bet. There seems to be an issue with the sample answer I compare with. I doubled checked in console and yours is right

Comment: only: the first element of an object is 0 and not 1 ( I forgot to mention that in the task)

Comment: Ok, so it's an index, what is second number - count or index of last element?

Comment: I think it is also an index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199318/discussion-between-barbsan-and-user2132380).

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, here's a function that behaves exactly like `Array.splice` for objects (don't know if this qualifies as "fancy" though):

```js
function spliceObject(obj, start, deleteCount, ...items) {
  let e = Object.entries(obj);
  let r = e.splice(start, deleteCount, ...items.flatMap(Object.entries));
  
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => delete obj[k]);
  e.forEach(([k, v]) => obj[k] = v);

  return Object.fromEntries(r);
}

//

obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6 }
ret = spliceObject(obj, 1, 3, {xyz:88}, {blah:99})
console.log(obj)
console.log(ret)
```

Do note however that you generally shouldn't rely on object properties being ordered in any particular way. The ordering is defined and mandated by the standard, but not all engines and tools get it right.

Answer (score 0):

For your default value question, this is a pattern that works well

```
function myfunction1(val) {
  this.val = val ? val : 1;
  console.log(this.val);
}
```